# Development Strategy For Reusable Django App

Tags: python, django

I've been reading guides, SO questions, and I watched a few videos on this subject but I can't really find the answer to what I am looking for.

So here's the situation. I had an app in my main project that I realized was a good candidate for a reusable app and I wanted to be able to use it in some of my side projects. So, I followed the official guide here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/reusable-apps/

That worked out great and I now have my app on PyPI. The issue is, how do I go about further developing it? Since I moved my app out of a Django project and into it's own directory where I can distribute/upload it, I can no longer run it.

I thought maybe I could turn that new directory into a Django project with its own setting.py and manage.py, etc. but I feel like there might be a better way.

I also thought about making a symlink to my app in another project and developing it indirectly, but that just seems dumb.

Either way, I'd like to make my repo (which is hosted publicly on github) to be runnable out of the box, so if someone wants to contribute they can just download it and start developing.

---

Edit:

The project I am specifically talking about is here: https://github.com/dummerbd/django-groundwork

The biggest issue is that it is hard to test on its own since it mostly deals with templates, which I am not too sure how to write good tests for without comparing a bunch of markup in assertions.

Comment: sorry, what does 'I can no longer run it' mean? cant you access to it?

Comment: Oh, I guess I should have clarified, since the app has been taken out of a Django project I can no longer run it using the Django development server.

Comment: It might be easier to give ideas for your specific case if you share the github link.

Comment: I recommend looking at how django-cms does it.  As for testing your templates... well, sometimes you just need to compare a bunch of markup in assertions, IF you feel you can write assertions that accurately reflect your requirements and don't include a bunch of other assumptions.

Comment: Well, maybe writing a decent test suite is the best way to test it, which means moving any logic into template tags/filters that can be easily tested. No matter what, I'll have to deal with templates, which I guess I can test in some staging Django project.

I looked at a few other package git repos but didn't see anything other than tests. I'll take a look at django-cms